# Create List View Action to call apex method

Tags: custom-object, custom-button, page-layout, list-view, custom-actions

I have a set of list views for my `Custom_Object__c` and these list views are visible in the community. I need to create a custom action for the `Custom_Object__c` list view. Then user should be able to mass update the status of each selected record to `Submitted`.

I was able to create a custom action and populate `Status` field to Submitted. Then user can save or cancel. Please see the image below.

[image]

But what I really need is, since I'm setting it only as `Submitted` I don't want the user to see what are the fields changing. In addition he should see just a confirmation window. The selected record ids should be passed to a apex method for further processing.

Is this capable? If so, please guide me.

Comment: Where's your code for the UI for that popup?

Answer (score 1):

The Lightning list view will does not allow you add the list view actions of all types. It will only allow custom actions of type Create a record or update a record. You already using the update a record custom action.

If you just want users to see a confirmation window, You can go with visualforce page having Standard List Controller. Read more here:- [Adding Custom List Buttons using Standard List Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_custom_button.htm)

You can customise your visualforce page according to your requirement.

Also, check this article to understand how best you can use visualforce in communities:-
[Use Visualforce in Lightning Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_use_visualforce.htm&type=5)